# Is there any equation to determine the waste heat produced in a pulsed laser system?

Tags: laser

By waste heat I mean how much the laser system would heat itself (and therefore it would be necessary to cool it down).

Simple equations are appreciated.

Comment: Hello, it depends a lot of the type of the laser. You can look the electrical to optical efficiency and assume the rest is heat. It is a rough approximation but it will give you an order of magnitude.

Comment: To a first approximation you can assume that all the power you pump into the gain medium is turned into heat. It gets more precise if you subtract the power leaving the laser as light and add the power consumption of the control electronics.

Comment: @Aliceo thanks for your answers. mm and how much waste do you think the 10 PW ELI laser produces every pulse? https://www.eli-beams.eu/facility/lasers/laser-4-aton-10-pw-2-kj/

Comment: A. P.  thanks for your answers. mm and how much waste do you think the 10 PW ELI laser produces every pulse? eli-beams.eu/facility/lasers/laser-4-aton-10-pw-2-kj – user287933 just now   Edit